# How to get the bow?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Can someone please tell me how to get the bow in *The Legend of Zelda Skyward Sword*?

Answer (score 2):

The bow can be found in the Sandship, after beating Scervo. Just keep following the story and you'll get it.